# Make a field to be obliged and unique , and use it to call recordings,

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

Please my friends I have a problem that blocks me what is the solution to make a field to be obliged and unique , and this field will servire like to call my reference recordings, 
I tried this solution but it is still accepting registrations with the same NumOffre.

```
class saisir_soumi(osv.osv):
_name='saisir.soumi' 

_rec_name = 'NumOffre'

_columns = {
    'NumOffre' : fields.char('N° Offre',required=True), # Must be obliged and unique 
    'organisme_s' : fields.char('Organisme',required=True),
    'taxe' : fields.selection([('17','17 %'),('12','12 %'),('10','10 %')],'Taxe Etablissement'),
    'des_offre' : fields.char('Designation de l\'offre'),
    'mont_marche' : fields.float('Montant Marché'),
    'date_depot' : fields.datetime('Date dépot'),
    'observation_s' : fields.text('Observation'),
    'order_line' : fields.one2many('saisir.soumi.ligne','order_id','soumission_id'),

    }
_sql_constraints = [
    ('uniq_NumOffre', 'unique(NumOffre,id)', "numero offre doit resté unique !"),
]
```

class saisir_soumi_ligne(osv.osv):
    _name ='saisir.soumi.ligne'

```
def onchange_value(self, cr, uid, ids, prix , quantite, context = None):
    return {'value': {'soustotal': prix * quantite}}

def on_change_produit(self, cr, uid, ids, product_id):
    val = {}
    prod = self.pool.get('product.product').browse(cr, uid, product_id)
    if prod:
        val['prix'] = prod.list_price
        val['qty_stock'] = prod.qty_available
        val['garantie'] = prod.warranty

    return {'value': val}

_columns= {
   'order_id': fields.many2one('saisir.soumission', 'Order Reference'),
   'product_id' : fields.many2one('product.product', 'Type Engin'),
   'quantite':fields.float(string='Quantité de soumi'),
   'qty_stock' : fields.float(string='Quantité Stock'),
   'marque' : fields.char('Marque'),
   'garantie' : fields.float('Garantie'),
   'prix' : fields.float('Prix Unitaire'),
   'soustotal' : fields.float('Sous total')
}
```

class saisir_soumi(osv.osv):
    _name ='saisir.soumi'

```
_columns= {
   'order_idd': fields.many2one('saisir.soumission', 'N° Offre'),
   'observation_d' : fields.text('Observation'),
   'Date_ouv_pli' : fields.date('Date Ouverture Plis'),
   'organisme_d' : fields.char('Organisme'),
   'nom_prenom_demar' : fields.char('Nom Démarcheur'),
   'date_depot_d' : fields.date('Date dépot de soumission'),
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constraint `unique(NumOffre,id)` restrict similar NumOffre **and** id, I think what you want is `unique(NumOffre)`. also you need to make sure that there are no duplicated field existed before the constraint otherwise it won't work.

Comment: The solution make constraint in PGAdmin in table it is easy and simple